# Pandas: Display events in lists grouped under same ID in date order from two different time series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, time-series

I have two dataframes corresponding to two different events.

```
Event A : 


Person_Id  |   Event_A_Date (yyyy-mm-dd) |  A_Reason (The suffix denotes whether X belongs to event A or B)

1            2020-04-01               X_A            

2            2020-03-29               X_A

1            2020-04-02               Y_A

3            2020-03-28               Z_A

2            2020-04-01               Z_A



Event B :

Person Id  |  Event_B_Date(yyyy-mm-dd)  | B_Reason

1             2020-04-03           Z_B

2             2020-03-30           Y_B

3             2020-03-29           X_B
```

Only the Person_Id column is common to both DFs.

Now, for each person ID, I want the list of their reasons corresponding to events A or B in the order of the occurence of events(By date).

That is, my desired output is :

```
Person_Id        |     Event_sequence

1                      [X_A, Y_A, Z_B]

2                      [X_A, Y_B, Z_A]

3                      [Z_A, X_B]
```

I am struggling to get this output using Python, since Person_ID is the only common column in both the dataframes.

Could someone please help me get this output using python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following steps:

(Assuming `df1` is the dataframe for `Event A` and `df2` is the dataframe for `Event B`)

**1) Unify the column names of the 2 dataframes**

```
df1a = df1.copy()
df1a.columns = ['Person_Id', 'Event_Date' ,'Reason']

df2a = df2.copy()
df2a.columns = ['Person_Id', 'Event_Date' ,'Reason']
```

**2) Combine the 2 new dataframes with `.append()`**

```
df = df1a.append(df2a)
```

**3) Sort the combined dataframe with `Person_Id` and `Event_Date`:**

```
df = df.sort_values(['Person_Id', 'Event_Date'])

   Person_Id  Event_Date Reason
0          1  2020-04-01    X_A
2          1  2020-04-02    Y_A
0          1  2020-04-03    Z_B
1          2  2020-03-29    X_A
1          2  2020-03-30    Y_B
4          2  2020-04-01    Z_A
3          3  2020-03-28    Z_A
2          3  2020-03-29    X_B
```

**4) Create the desired layout by `.groupby()` and `.agg`, as follows:**

```
df_out = df.groupby('Person_Id')['Reason'].agg(list).reset_index(name='Event_sequence')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


   Person_Id   Event_sequence
0          1  [X_A, Y_A, Z_B]
1          2  [X_A, Y_B, Z_A]
2          3       [Z_A, X_B]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Just a small question, In case person_id is not an 'int' and contains some alphanumeric characters, I could still sort by 'person_id' by considering it as an 'object' type right ? That shouldn't make any difference right ?

Comment: @AnonymousMe  Yes, string (object) types can also be sorted. It will be in alphabetical order then.  Actually, you can also sort on `Event_date` only on the sort step.  The `.groupby()` command will sort by the group key (ie.  `Person_Id`) at the final step.  Both numeric fields and strings are fine.

Comment: @AnonymousMe If you don't want to sort by `Person_Id` order, you can also use `groupby('Person_Id', sort=False)` in the last statement when you also not sort in it in the previous sort step.